# as2 calculate turn rate between xy and xy

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, physics

My First question on here so be kind...

I am writing an aerodrome simulator in as2, I need to calculate a turn rate between 2 points so that the aircraft turns nicely. I have tried a few things but the maths forums on this type of subject use complex calculations and I struggle to understand them. I need an answer in a more variable specific format.

I have the XY of both tile and target, the speed of tile and the distance of target from the tile.

[image: Turn Example]

I use vector math, with frame time calculations to move the tile. I already have a good calculation for shortest turn i.e. left right.

I need to calculate the turn rate required to go from point a to point b in a nice fluid motion and turn the tile/aircraft in a nice fashion.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 'Tween' class to animate the turn of the aircraft. You can read the specs here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html